# How do i get the value of a SHELL environment variable in java

Tags: java

on linux command line:

1. export DB_SYSTEM=mysql
2. echo $DB_SYSTEM 
      result = mysql
3. Within Java , i want to access and print value of DB_SYSTEM

could it be:

```
public Properties getEnvironment() throws java.io.IOException {
    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.load(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("env").getInputStream());
    return env;
    }

Properties env = getEnvironment();
String myEnvVar = env.get("DB_SYSTEM");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `System.getenv`:

```
String dbSystem = System.getenv("DB_SYSTEM");
```

If you call it with no arguments, it returns all the environment variables:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String dbSystem = env.get("DB_SYSTEM");
```

Comment: Thanks, just one additional question, HOW would the IDE / JVM know of the Shell Environment? inmy case, i am testing this using Netbeans and in the Shell i declare $ export DB_SYSTEM=mysql, and when i try ot print it in netbeans / JVM, i get "null"

Comment: @kamal: Make sure: 1. `export` first. 2. Run NetBeans from that _same_ shell. (i.e., type `netbeans` directly into that same shell, don't launch it from an icon or something.)